# Python add strings together

Tags: python, string, datetime

I am trying to to construct the folloiwng line which is the object from the holidays package:

```
holidays.DE()
```

I want to split it as the following:

**holidays** and **.DE()** as parameter. As string it does not work tried it already and receiving the following error message:

**HOLIDAYS_German = holidays+Option TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'module' and 'str'**

How can I solve it?

The code looks like the following:

```
import datetime as dt
import holidays

def BDCTest(date1,date2,Option):

    HOLIDAYS_German = holiday+Option

    for i in range((date2 - date1).days + 1):
        nextday = date1 + dt.timedelta(days=i)
        if nextday not in HOLIDAYS_German:
            print(nextday.strftime('%d-%m-%y'))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    date1 = dt.datetime.strptime('22-12-16', '%d-%m-%y')
    date2 = dt.datetime.strptime('22-12-17', '%d-%m-%y')
    Option = '.DE'

    Test = BDCTest(date1,date2, Option)
```

Comment: If you really wanted to go down your route, you could do `exec("%s()" %HOLIDAYS_German)` which is okay if you're not exposing this to user input. It involves an addition of a single line of code, but is quite dirty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just putting two strings together does not make Python execute those strings.

Dynamic attribute access is done with the [`getattr()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr); `DE` just an attribute on the `holidays` module, one that happens to be callable:

```
Option = 'DE'
HOLIDAYS_German = getattr(holiday, Option)()
```

So `getattr()` retrieves the `DE` attribute of the `holiday` object (a module), and the result is called. Note that `Option` does *not* start with a `.`!

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for.